# ReactJs packery example

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get to grips with more complex reactjs components. One I example I would like to get working is this packery one

So this is the basic component for the Hellworld example

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

//jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7xzd92s5/4/

taking this forward I would like to get this packery example working - but how do I include the  react-packery-mixin - is there a cnd for it. Is this example complete? https://tonicdev.com/npm/nexts-react-packery-mixin

```
var PackeryMixin = require('react-packery-mixin');

var packeryOptions = {
    transitionDuration: 0
};

var Packer = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'SomeComponent',

    mixins: [PackeryMixin('packeryContainer', packeryOptions)],

    render: function () {
        var childElements = this.props.elements.map(function(element){
           return (
                <div className="someclass">
                    {element.name}
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div ref="packeryContainer">
                {childElements}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Packer name="Packer" />,
  document.getElementById('Packer')
);
```

Comment: I've got this working with a masonry example - but need to replace a lot of depreciated elements - https://jsfiddle.net/7xzd92s5/47/

Comment: latest version https://jsfiddle.net/7xzd92s5/48/